# SKTransition transitionWithCIFilter:duration: not animating

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, transition, core-image

I've been trying to create a page-turn transition between scenes in SpriteKit like this:

```
+ (SKTransition *)pageTurnTransition {
    float w = 768.0;
    float h = 1024.0;
    CIVector *extent = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:w W:h];

    CIImage *shadingImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2]];

    CIImage *blankImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1]];

    CIFilter *pageCurlFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPageCurlTransition"
                                          keysAndValues:
                                @"inputExtent", extent,
                                @"inputShadingImage", shadingImage,
                                @"inputBacksideImage", blankImage,
                                @"inputAngle",[NSNumber numberWithFloat: -0.2*M_PI],
                                @"inputRadius", [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 70],
                                nil
                                ];
    return [SKTransition transitionWithCIFilter:pageCurlFilter duration:1];
}
```

This is how I call the transition:

```
SKScene *spaceshipScene = [[SpaceshipScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[[self view] presentScene:spaceshipScene transition:[HelloScene pageTurnTransition]];
```

The problem is that the transition does not animate, it just stays at the original scene for the specified (1 second) duration of the transition, then abruptly shows the next scene.

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong? I've tested this in the iPad simulator iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it could reproduce your problem.

It seems to be an issue with the CurlTransition. If you use one of the built in transitions it works:

```
return [SKTransition doorsCloseVerticalWithDuration:2];
```

Are you sure that the shadingImage mustn't be transparent?

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is somewhere with the CI filter not running properly or having its parameters not passed in correctly, but I can't find any information about it. I have tried to pass a sample semi-transparent image into inputShadingImage, but the result is the same. Perhaps there is a special format the shading image must be in?

Comment: Also the pageCurlFilter does not initialize, it is nil.

Comment: The pageCurlFilter is not supported in iOS. You can check with this code: NSArray *Filters = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn];